# Apache VirtualHost and ModProxy not working as hoped

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-proxy, tomcat6

I have 3 wars set up on a Tomcat instance - these wars are being served at:

- http://machine:9023/war1
- http://machine:9023/war2
- http://machine:9023/war3

I have Apache on the same machine. I am trying to set Apache up so that I can access the 3 wars in the following way:

- http://war1.mycompany.com:9024/ [yes, port 9024]
- http://war2.mycompany.com:9024/
- http://war3.mycompany.com:9024/

I have tried following the example [Using Virtual_Host and mod_proxy together](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#proxy), but it is not working correctly. When I visit http://war1.mycompany.com/ the browser gets sent a `302` towards http://war1.mycompany.com/war1/ and that in return gives a `400` error.

If I visit http://war1.mycompany.com:9023/war1 (ie query Tomcat directly) then I get the site I am expecting, so the DNS is set up correctly, and the war is correctly deployed.

My Apache configuration file (`/etc/httpd/conf.d/sites.conf`) is as follows:

```
Listen 9024
<VirtualHost *:9024>
    ServerAdmin admin@mycompany.com
    ServerName war1.mycompany.com
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9023/war1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9023/war1
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using Apache 2.2.3 and Tomcat 6.0.14. Tomcat is configured pretty much normally:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
</Host>
```

The wars are in `CATALINA_HOME/webapps/war1.war`, etc.

What am I doing wrong? Is there something I should be looking for in the main Apache configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick edit: are you sure it's Apache giving you the error 400, btw? Use 'curl -v ' and examine the header traffic to ensure it's Apache that's 400'ing.

Hmmm, it *looks* right. Do you have a 'NameVirtualHost *:9024" somewhere in your config? And, are you sure the mod_proxy* modules are actually enabled via LoadModule somewhere?

Try using an alternate method:

```
<Location />
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9023/war1
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9023/war1
  #
  # Perhaps your Tomcat is HTTP/1.1 buggy?
  SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
  SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
</Location>
```

I suggest setting your 'LogLevel debug' to examine the actual traffic to determine what's going wrong.